# How to refresh dataTable after closing a popup

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable, modal-dialog, refresh

I have tried to refresh my table after adding a new articles to it using a popup but my code doesn't do what I need to, it work normally but without refreshing my table
**this my createModal function**

```
createModal(){
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(SelectNewArticleModalComponent,{ size: 'lg' });
    //modalRef.componentInstance.id = undefined;
    modalRef.result.then(() =>{
    this.tournee = this.creationTourneeService.getTournee();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
    );
  }
```

inside the modal I tried to add my data to a local attribut named "tournee" in the service

**this my modal component.ts**

```
export class SelectNewArticleModalComponent implements
  OnInit,
  OnDestroy {
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  codes: string[];
  detail: Observable<Article[]>
  articles: Article[] = [];
  constructor(public modal: NgbActiveModal,
    public articleService: ArticleService,
    private creationTourneeService: CreationTourneeService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.articleService.fetchNonSelectedArticle(this.creationTourneeService.getTournee().code);
    this.loadForm();
    const sb = this.articleService.isLoading$.subscribe(res => this.isLoading = res);
    this.subscriptions.push(sb);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach((sb) => sb.unsubscribe());
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modal.dismiss();
  }

  loadForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      articles: [this.articles],
    });
  }
  SaveArticles() {
    const tournee = this.creationTourneeService.getTournee();
    for(let code of this.grouping.getSelectedRows()){
      this.articleService.getItemByCode(code).subscribe(res=>{
        const detailTournee: DetailTournee = new DetailTournee();
        detailTournee.article = res;
        detailTournee.articleCode = res.code;
        tournee.detailTournees.push(detailTournee);
      });
    }
    this.creationTourneeService.setTournee(tournee);
    
    this.modal.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your shared code in the question, there seems a problem that you are refreshing the table data before insert.

So try to wait for a few seconds to let data insert into database and then refresh it.

Try replacing your modal close callback function with below:-

```
modalRef.result.then(() => {
  setTimeout(() =>{ 
    this.tournee = this.creationTourneeService.getTournee();
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: I tried what u have wrote but still doesn't work until I made some change in the table

Comment: I hope its working now. If yes, can you write the changes you made pls.

Comment: Would you be able to upload it to stackblitz or somewhere so that will be easy to look into and debug

Comment: Another solution could be- make this.creationTourneeService.setTournee Observable so that you can subscribe it to get it executed and in the subscribe, emit an Event and subscribe that event in the list page and in the subscription of that event, refresh the table data. So as soon as the data is inserted, it will emit an event and the data will be refreshed.

Comment: I found a solution to this issue by adding changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  you helped me a lot, thank you
 this is the change I have made 
modalRef.result.then(() => {
      setTimeout(() =>{ 
        this.tournee = this.creationTourneeService.getTournee();
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }, 1000);
  });

Comment: Glad I could help :)